# Low VPN (PPTP, OpenVPN) performance on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, raspberry-pi, pptp

I own a raspberry pi modebl b+ with Raspbian and kernel 3.12.26+ installed.

I recompiled the kernel and enabled pptp module in order to use it with `pptp_accel`

Using the same VPN provider and their windows tool I'm getting 100/6 mbps on windows machine. I.e. without any slowdown, my connection is 100/6. However, when I use the same provider on raspberry and connect via PPTP with the accel, the speed is 10-11/6. And most interesting is that the CPU load is around 0 at the moment of running speedtest.

Yes, I'm sure that I was connected when testing from Windows using the tool, I saw the VPN provider IP everywhere on whatismyipaddress, it really loaded youtube content blocked here and so on.

I don't know what protocol the Windows tool uses, but I'm really interested in why raspberry shows ~10 times lower speed with 0% cpu load.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Here is how the raspberry looks, this is to show that only ethernet and power cables are connected.

[skipped as I need >=10 reputation to post more than 2 links or images]

Here are pppd options file in use:

```
#pty "pptp ru1.******.com --nolaunchpppd"
connect /bin/true
plugin "/usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/pptp.so"


pptp_server *************

user "user"
password "password"

#defaultroute
#replacedefaultroute
#lock
noauth
nobsdcomp
nodeflate
nodetach
remotename ru
ipparam ru
require-mppe-128
usepeerdns
#mtu 1452
#mru 1452
```

Here is the speedtest when raspberry is connected to the VPN provider with PPTP:

[image]

Here is the speedtest to the same server and using the same server of the VPN provider when connecting directly from my windows machine to the provider using their tool:

[image]

**As for the OpenVPN**: let's put it away for a moment, it's actually a bit slower than PPTP due to stronger encryption and CPU load is higher on raspberry because of that. Let's sort out pptp first. As I said, CPU load is 0 on raspberry when speedtest'ing

Comment: as far as i know, the raspberry ethernet port shares bandwidth with usb ports. have you tried using cabled ethernet with nothing in the usb ports? and is compression turned on for openvpn? try turning it off

Comment: I cannot see how OpenVPN is related to this problem. Care to explain?

Comment: See my updates in the original post. And thanks for looking into this